# No socket available error while running JUnit test case in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

No socket available error in eclipse while running a simple JUnit test case. 
I have got all required jars in my build path. I did all googling stuff.
None of the blogs helped:(

Comment: What's the simple unit test looking like? Is there a stacktrace with the error? If yes, what's it looking like. A bit more information is needed here to be able to help.

Comment: No stack trace errors are present. A pop-up saying no socket available is popping up in eclipse IDE.

Comment: Look into the eclipse logfile if you can see more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution (at least in my case).

Eclipse was installed on a company share drive once I moved it to my local C drive everything worked fine.